# Sort a table's query according to another table's value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, join

Here is the scenario:
I want to sort names in table1 according to ages in table2. Whats the SQL query?

table1

```
ID | Name
---|-----
1  | Jack
2  | Tony
3  | John
```

and this is table2

```
ID | Age
---|-----
1  | 17
2  | 18
3  | 15
```

Both tables are related with `ID` field.

Comment: Which field joins both table?

Comment: both table must have relationship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to join both tables and then you can order by `table2.Age`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   table1 t1 
       JOIN Table2 t2 
           ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY Age
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8284a3/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.age 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
order by t2.age
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ID field is the JOIN column for both the tables and considering the purpose of the columns, they should ideally be in a single table as they have one-to-one correspondence.

If your example is not apt for your question, then you would write a query to JOIN both the tables, select only columns that are of interest (from one or both the tables) and sort on the column from the appropriate table.